# Sorting a perl array of arrays

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have a table in an array and I am trying to sort it using the following method:

```
@table_array = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @table_array;
```

But I get this error:

```
Can't use string ("5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at
```

My `$table_array[x][0]` is a numeric value. I create this table by reading two files and merging them on a common field (`$table_array[x][1]` to be exact).

I am not able to understand where I have asked the elements to be accessed using string references.

Thanks,
Karthick S.

Comment: See [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My `$table_array[x][0]` is a numeric value.

No, that's not true. For one of the elements, `$table_array[x]` is `5` instead of a reference.

```
>perl -e"use strict; $a=5; $a->[0]"
Can't use string ("5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at -e line 1.
```

Maybe you did

```
$table_array[$x] = @rec;
```

instead of

```
$table_array[$x] = \@rec;
```